# Kendo UI multiple grid Excel export

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Here is the code I'm using to export Kendo multiple grid to Excel, how can I export with all pages

[Example - multiple grid Excel export](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/excel/multiple-grid-export)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #products .k-grid-toolbar
    {
         display:none !important;
    }
   </style>    
</head>
<body>

<button id="export" class="k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Export to Excel</button>
<div id="products"></div>
<div id="orders"></div>
<script>
  // used to sync the exports
  var promises = [
    $.Deferred(),
    $.Deferred()
  ];

  $("#export").click(function(e){
    // trigger export of the products grid
    $("#products").data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel();
    // trigger export of the orders grid
    $("#orders").data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel();
    // wait for both exports to finish
    $.when.apply(null, promises)
     .then(function(productsWorkbook, ordersWorkbook) {

      // create a new workbook using the sheets of the products and orders workbooks
      var sheets = [
        productsWorkbook.sheets[0],
        ordersWorkbook.sheets[0]
      ];

      sheets[0].title = "Products";
      sheets[1].title = "Orders";

      var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
        sheets: sheets
      });

      // save the new workbook,b
      kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
        fileName: "ProductsAndOrders.xlsx"
      })
    });
  });

  $("#products").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                allPages: true
    },
    dataSource: {
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
          dataType: "jsonp"
        }
      },
      pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 550,
    pageable: true,
    excelExport: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      promises[0].resolve(e.workbook);
    }
  });

  $("#orders").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      pageSize: 20,
      serverPaging: true
    },
    height: 550,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
      { field:"OrderID" },
      { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name" },
      { field: "ShipCity", title: "Ship City" }
    ],
    excelExport: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      promises[1].resolve(e.workbook);
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: It works, thanks. But if I edit my grids then update, it just exports old data not new.

Comment: Could you please provide your code snippet?

Comment: Here is my code, thanks for help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663647/how-to-export-kendo-multiple-grid-after-grid-refresh-display-new-datas)